# Menu ISSUES with some Android 4.x devices

Tags: android, menu

I have an app that has been working fine, but suddenly some users running 4.0 devices (not all) are claiming the menu isn't working...

I have a menu with more than 6 options or whatever Android shows by default. 
The users are complaining that when they click on the **MORE** button that shows the remaining options, the pop up list showing all the other options appears but they can't click on any of the options. The list that pops up does not accept any user actions other than the back button, which closes it.

Does anyone have any idea WHY this would be going on?  I am unable to reproduce the error on any device I have or on any emulator that I have.... I am assuming I am dealing with some fragmentation issue or OS change issue as the code is about as basic as it can be.

Anyone have any ideas?  Was menuing significantly changed in some way that could cause this to happen?

Comment: I have no idea about, but please show us Your piece of code where You are creating and using this menu. Maybe we could see an issue or something that has changed since Android 4.0

Comment: Sure, I'll post it later today, but its just a basic onCreateOptionsMenu,  onOptionsItemSelected model... nothing fancy about it.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense, sometimes the MORE submenu on the options menu works flawlessly, other times it appears but nothing is clickable.. Yet, when I click on the BACK button and select the MORE button again the menu functions as it should.

Comment: I just gave up on this, there is CLEARLY a bug in menuing in 4.x vs 2.x when you have more than 6 Menu items at least on some devices... it is annoying and inconsistent, but clearly in the OS.  I worked around by creating my own MORE submenu as my sixth menu item and put my other items under it.

Comment: I have users complaining about exactly the same issue, one of them on a Galaxy Note 2. I can't reproduce the issue even on my own Note 2.

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to figure it out, its CLEARLY a bug in 4.x... and it is inconsistent, I could reproduce it inconsistently on a Tab 2 and the emulator.  The work around was the simplest fix.  Create your own MORE button and put the options under it and handle it yourself.

Comment: Haven't seen this before. You guys should file a bug report if that is true... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: @user282172: There are apps out there that have the **More** option in the menu and they work on all versions of Android 4 (aka JellyBean), like **[Catlog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en)** for instance. Post your codes and log file. Maybe there's an issue with your menu creation. Put a log statement in the `onOptionsItemSelected` and see if it gets called.

Answer (score 2):

if i understood you issue properly then I had faced a similar type of issue,

issue--2.x has one dedicated key for menu but in 4.x do not has so we need check that in on create..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_list);
        checkMenu();
                   //other stuff
        }
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void checkMenu() {
    boolean hasMenu = ViewConfiguration.get(this).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        if (!hasMenu) {
            try {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.class.getField( "FLAG_NEEDS_MENU_KEY").getInt(null));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```